# Output in GeoJSON data format using Ruby

Tags: geojson, library, ruby

I have some data with Ruby script (obtained by geolocating, loading from config files etc) that I want to output as a GeoJSON file.

I have some ugly code that generates valid geojson files - but is there existing standard for doing this?

I need it into another script and thought about extracting my code into a gem. But I suspect that there is existing library for that, and I simply failed to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/phildionne/geojson_model is nice

```
require 'geojson_model'
require 'json'

locations = []
locations << GeojsonModel::Feature.new(
    properties: {name: 'Null Island'},
    geometry: GeojsonModel::Geometry.new(type: 'Point', coordinates: [0, 0])
    )
locations << GeojsonModel::Feature.new(
    properties: {name: 'Kraków'},
    geometry: GeojsonModel::Geometry.new(type: 'Point', coordinates: [20, 50])
    )
locations << GeojsonModel::Feature.new(
    properties: {name: 'Marker of former Prime Meridiam'},
    geometry: GeojsonModel::Geometry.new(type: 'Point', coordinates: [-0.0014862, 51.4779959])
    )

fc = GeojsonModel::FeatureCollection.new(features: locations)
puts(JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(fc.to_json)))
```